# Greatest number of own goals in Europe

Tags: football, trivia, records

Which player has scored the greatest number of own goals in the top five European Leagues (as measured by UEFA coefficient: La Liga, Serie A, Premier League, Bundesliga, Ligue 1)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For the Premier League it is **Richard Dunne** [Source](https://www.worldfootball.net/alltime_goalgetter/eng-premier-league/eigentore/1/%22Source%22)

For the Bundesliga there are two players who are tied: **Manfred Kaltz** & **Nikolce Noveski** [Source from the Bundesliga Website](https://www.bundesliga.com/en/news/Bundesliga/hoffenheim-s-kevin-akpoguma-scores-1000th-bundesliga-own-goal-464057.jsp)

For La Liga the top own goal scorer is **Fernando Caceres** [La Liga Source](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/laliga/eigentorstatistik/wettbewerb/ES1/plus/?saison_id=gesamt)

In Serie A there are two players who are tied with 8 own goals: **Riccardo Ferrari** and **Franco Baresi** [Source for Serie A](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/serie-a/eigentorstatistik/wettbewerb/IT1/plus/?saison_id=gesamt)

In Ligue 1 there are a couple of players who are tied for being #1 in own goals. Here are some: **Aly Cissokho**, **Anthony Weber**, **Damien Da Silva** all with 4 own goals. [Source for Ligue 1](https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/ligue-1/eigentorstatistik/wettbewerb/FR1/plus/?saison_id=gesamt)

If you are looking who the Top Own goal scorer is between these 5 leagues, it would be **Richard Dunne** with **10** own goals.

Comment: It would be helpful if you also mentioned how many own golas scored every player you named.